# How/should I replace nested foreach with one linq query?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, foreach, nested

Trying to set a property on certain labels contained in a Windows Forms GroupBox, I wrote the loops below.  This works fine, but I don't like it due to its (I think unnecessary) double foreach nesting.

I have tried to rewrite this to be more clear, use only one foreach, and a combined Linq expression, but all my attempts fail at runtime with a CastException, either from GroupBox to Label or vice versa.

Is there a more clear, more efficient, or more readable way to write this loop construct?

> ```
>         foreach (var gb in (from Control c in this.Controls where c is GroupBox select c))
>             foreach (Label tlbl in (from Control a in gb.Controls
>                                     where a is Label && a.Tag != null && a.Tag.ToString() == "answer"
>                                     select a))
>                 tlbl.ForeColor = (tlbl.Name.Replace("lbl", "") == rb.Name) ? afterSelectColor : beforeSelectColor;
> ```

Readability is my highest goal.  With that in mind, is it worth trying to rewrite it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend you do the editing in a `foreach`, as LINQ is not meant to cause side effects. Like this:

```
foreach (Label tlbl in (this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>()
    .SelectMany(g => g.Controls.Cast<Control>()).OfType<Label>()
    .Where(a => a.Tag != null && a.Tag.ToString() == "answer")))
{
    tblb.ForeColour = tlbl.Name.Replace("lbl", "") == rb.Name ? afterSelectColor : beforeSelectColor;
}
```

Note `SelectMany` in here. That's how you translate nested `foreach` loops to LINQ, as it is pretty much just a nested `foreach` loop.

Comment: Good answers, all. But I find this most readable, and without the side effects that Eric Lippert advises against.  Thanks!

Comment: I should have tried it first.  This does not compile, giving "The type argument for method SelectMany cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Comment: @shipr That was my fault, fixed now. Whoops ^^'

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance your code does not compile see my edit.

Comment: @HighCore Fixed the other error. I've never used winforms before, that's why I didn't know that.

Comment: @newSTackExchangeInstance neither did I. I had to create a new "WindowsFormsApplication1" to test this.

Answer (score 1):

```
Controls.OfType<GroupBox>
        .SelectMany(x => x.Controls.OfType<Label>)
        .Where(x => x.Tag != null && x.Tag.ToString() == "answer")
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => x ForeColor = (x.Name.Replace("lbl", "") == rb.Name) ? afterSelectColor : beforeSelectColor);
```

Notice that the `ForEach()` method is not part of LINQ. It's a member of the `List<T>` class.
LinQ is a functional feature, therefore it's methods are not supposed to affect the source objects. That's why there's no `ForEach()` in LINQ.

**Edit:**

If you don't like the use of `List<T>.ForEach()`, then you may also do it this way:

```
var labels = Controls.OfType<GroupBox>
                     .SelectMany(x => x.Controls.OfType<Label>)
                     .Where(x => x.Tag != null && x.Tag.ToString() == "answer")

foreach (var label in labels)
{
  label.ForeColor = (label.Name.Replace("lbl", "") == rb.Name) ? afterSelectColor : beforeSelectColor);
}
```

While this separates the code in 2 statements, it improves readability a lot compared to other approaches.

**Edit2:**

Since this is winforms, the `Control.Controls` collection is not an `IEnumerable<T>`, but an `IEnumerable` therefore the `OfType<T>` must be included inside the `SelectMany()` expression. Corrected that.

Comment: Missed out a Many, but nearly there.

Comment: LINQ is spelt as previously, not LinQ.